# How TransactionScope works with DTC and WCF?

Tags: msdtc

I have WCF Service with following coding:

```
using (TransactionScope transScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
{
     security = new Security(GetConnection(SecurityConstants.DatabaseName));
     int userExists = security.UserRegistered(UserID,Pass);
     transScope.Complete();                
}
```

I have same method in DBA layer to run query by IExecuteResult as you can see here:

```
         [Function(Name = SecurityConstants.SP_Name)]
        public UserRegistered<IntegerOutput> IsUserExist(
        [Parameter(Name = "USERID", DbType  = "VarChar(15)")] string userID, 
        [Parameter(Name = "pass", DbType = "VarChar(25)")] string pass
            )
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this,((MethodInfo)   (MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), userID, pass);
            return ((ISingleResult<IntegerOutput>)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
```

Furthermore, I have checked MSDTC's configuration, but when I run my application it face to "Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed" error. I have enabled DTC on my local machine and server side, but I still have problem. could you let me know is it for network setting or my local mochine or something else? could you please help me.